# Printed Plots are all Black with Octave in Cygwin using gnuplot

Tags: printing, plot, cygwin, gnuplot, octave

I've been trying to setup Octave in cygwin and it was straight forward to get it up and running, however I cannot print plots to a file properly.  When I plot in Octave I see the plot on the screen correctly, but printing it to a file only results in a black rectangle with axis markers.

From what I've researched it appears that gnuplot 5.0 has a bug in it (http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?42838).  I tried reverting to gnuplot 4, but it did not work in cygwin and complained about not having the cyggd-2.dll file.  I tried finding the package in cygwin that had this file (libgd2) but it doesn't exist in cygwin's package repository anymore and has been replaced by libgd3.

I also tried upgrading to gnuplot 5.1 by downloading the binaries from (http://www.tatsuromatsuoka.com/gnuplot/Eng/cygbin/).  However, this didn't seem to resolve the problem; though it's possible that I did not install them correctly.

At this point I'm not sure what else to try.  I've tried different file output formats, but all give the same black rectangle with visible axes.  I tried EPS, PNG, JPEG, and PDF.

Has anyone been able to get Octave to correctly print figures with gnuplot 5 in cygwin?  If so, how?  What do I need to do?

Could I possibly use another graphics toolkit?  I looked into using FLTK, but couldn't get that to work either.  I can register the FLTK graphics toolkit, but when I attempt to instruct Octave to use FLTK for the graphics toolkit I receive the following error: `__init_fltk__: no graphics DISPLAY available`

Comment: What was the problem with FLTK? Is there a particular reason that you use cygwin? If not I would suggest the Octave 4.0rc4 MXE build.

Comment: When I attempt to set the graphics toolkit to FLTK I get the following error: `__init_fltk__: no graphics DISPLAY available`.  I'm also using cygwin because I eventually want this to run on a Linux system, but I'd like to develop on my Windows machine.  I'll update the post to reflect the information added here.

Comment: You need to install and run The XWin server

Answer (score 0):

I could get around by manually pointing to gnuplot 4.6 which I had on another cygwin installation

i.e. replace /usr/bin/gnuplot.exe with 4.6-version and copy folder /usr/share/gnuplot/4.6/

I'm using Octave 3.8.2 on a windows7x86 machine

Comment: I tried reverting to gnuplot 4.x, but since I don't have an old install of cygwin I didn't have the library to go with it (cyggd-2.dll).  I might be able to find a copy of it and place it on my system, but who knows how many other files I'd be missing.